# Why doesn't 'wp' command work in my WP-CLI installation?

Tags: wp-cli

The wp-cli.phar file is in the same directory from where I test the `wp` command. But it says the command doesn't exist.

When I'm trying to see if [WP-CLI](https://wp-cli.org/#installing) is installed with the `php wp-cli.phar --info` command, it looks like this:

```
root@new-web-node:/var/www/vhosts/mywebsite.com/httpdocs# php wp-cli.phar --info
OS: Linux 3.13.0-141-generic #190-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jan 19 12:52:38 UTC 2018 x86_64
Shell:  /bin/bash
PHP binary: /usr/bin/php5
PHP version:    5.5.9-1ubuntu4.23
php.ini used:   /etc/php5/cli/php.ini
WP-CLI root dir:    phar://wp-cli.phar
WP-CLI vendor dir:  phar://wp-cli.phar/vendor
WP_CLI phar path:   /var/www/vhosts/mywebsite.com/httpdocs
WP-CLI packages dir:    
WP-CLI global config:   
WP-CLI project config:  
WP-CLI version: 1.5.0
```

What is wrong? And how to fix it?

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you need to rename the wp-cli.phar to wp.

```
chmod +x wp-cli.phar
sudo mv wp-cli.phar /usr/local/bin/wp
```

I usually move wp to my home folder's bin directory so /home/YOUR_USER_NAME/bin

now try:

```
wp --info
```